# Can't connect to local hortonworks sandbox with ssh

Tags: ssh, virtualbox

I've deployed the Hortonworks Sandbox on VirtualBox according to https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/section/1/ .

Now, I want to ssh to the sandbox. I see this in the shell of the virtual machine:

[image]

If you zoom in on the middle of the image, you'll see this:

[image].

Assuming the IP-adress of the virtual machine to be `http://127.0.0.1`, I did the following:

```
$ ssh root@http://127.0.0.1 -p 8888
ssh: Could not resolve hostname http://127.0.0.1: Name or service not known
```

As you can see, it doesn't work. How come it is not found? I can connect through my browser by going to 127.0.0.1:8888, so clearly, there is something there. Why can't I find it with ssh?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the ip-address and the port. Changed the command to:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

which solved the problem.